# How to make POCO work with Linq-to-SQL with complex relationships in DDD

Tags: linq-to-sql, domain-driven-design, poco, ddd-repositories

I am struggling to find a way to make POCOs work with Linq-to-Sql when my domain model is not table-driven - meaning that my domain objects do not match-up with the database schema.

For example, in my domain layer I have an Appointment object which has a Recurrence property of type Recurrence.  This is a base class with several subclasses each based on a specific recurrence pattern.

In my database, it makes no sense to have a separate AppointmentRecurrences table when there is always a one-to-one relationship between the Appointment record and its recurrence.  So, the Appointments table has RecurrenceType and RecurrenceValue columns.  RecurrenceType has a foreign key relationship to the RecurrenceTypes table because there is a one-to-many relationship between the recurrence type (pattern) and the Appointments table.

Unless there is a way to create the proper mapping between these two models in Linq-to-Sql, I am left with manually resolving the impedence mismatch in code.

This becomes even more difficult when it comes to querying the database using the Specification pattern.  For example, if I want to return a list of current appointments, I can easily create a Specification object that uses the following Expression: `appt => appt.Recurrence.IsDue`.  However, this does not translate into the Linq-to-SQL space because the source type of the Expression is not one that L2S recognizes (e.g. it's not the L2S entity).

So how can I create the complex mapping in Linq-to-SQL to support my domain model?

Or, is there a better way to implement the Specification pattern in this case?  I'd thought about using interfaces that would be implemented by both my domain object and the L2S entity (through partials) but that's not possible with the impedence mismatch of the two object graphs.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Linq to SQL pretty much forces you into a class-per-table model, it does not support mapping a single entity class to several database tables.

Even more unfortunately, there are very few ORM's that will support more complicated mappings, and vanishingly few that do and offer decent LINQ support.  The only I'm even remotely sure of is NHibernate (our experiences with Entity Framework rate it really no better than L2S in this regard).

Also, trying to use the specification pattern in LINQ expressions is going to be quite the challenge.

Even with ORM's, and even with a really strong abstracting ORM like NHibernate, there is still a large impedence mismatch to overcome.

Comment: I agree with Brian that working with Expressions is not a problem and I already have the framework in place. My problem is with the impedence mismatch. I'm not sure how anyone can truly follow DDD with this restriction as it is quite likely that my domain objects will be structured very differently than the way data is stored since one models behavior and the other stores state with the goal of at least trying to normalize the data. Seems like a major oversight in MS' ORM initiatives and explains why so many DDD examples are using NHibernate.

Comment: So it seems my options are limited. If L2S is going to generate entities in a class-per-table manner, then I can go ahead and create my domain objects as originally planned (and in a DDD way) then leave resolving the mismatch to the Repository class and I guess I will have to put aside the Specification pattern for now.  Unfortunately this puts the logic required to execute a query inside the Repository which is totally undesirable, but alas...

Comment: Ya it's a bummer the MS tools just aren't quite up to a clean, decoupled domain layer.

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://blogs.rev-net.com/ddewinter/2009/05/31/linq-expression-trees-and-the-specification-pattern/) explains how to use the specification pattern with linq-to-sql.  The specifications can be chained together which builds up an expression tree that can be used by your repository and therefore linq-to-sql.

I haven't tried implementing it yet, but the linq-to-entities version is on my to-do list for a project I am currently working on.

Comment: works ok as long as all your specifications rely only on logic that can be translated from LINQ to SQL (basically, primitive comparisons on fields that are directly represented in the DB).  As soon as your needs go beyond the simplest of scenarios this falls flat on its face.

Comment: Yea, I'm familiar with the Specification pattern and it was my intent to use the pattern so that I could define the specifications in my domain layer and pass them to the data layer where they would be used to resolve any searches. The only way to do this is to go full POCO which is possible with L2S usign the XML Mapping file but having to structure my domain objects to match the database schema so that L2S can map them is a real problem for me and undermine's DDD, imo. After all, I don't care how normalized the database is when creating my domain objects but it appears now that I do care.